# Should I check if Entity exists before getting/deleting with Spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring data jpa has some Exceptions that it throws, like EntityNotFoundException, but they are not descriptive enough and I though it would be good to check if Entity exists, if not - throw an Exception with a nice description.
Is that a good decision or is it just a redundant SQL query and it is better to stick stick to Spring data jpa exceptions?

Comment: So the entity is created but when you try to delete something it doesn't find it ? 
Can you show an exemple of code where you trying to delete ?

Comment: @KASMIG. it finds it, I am building an API and thinking about exception handling. If I should make descriptive custom exceptions or do not care about it at all and let Spring data JPA exceptions be instead of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jpa Repository has been adapted to work with optionals as well. In that case EntityNotFoundException is not thrown.

ex `Optional<User> findByName(String name)`

So just check if optional `isPresent()` and that will be enough